# Baby Rudin Theorem 5.15 (Taylor's Theorem) continuity requirement

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, taylor-expansion

In the proof, Rudin defines $g(t) = f(t) - P(t) - M(t - \alpha)^n$ and apply Mean Value Theorem (MVT) to $g$ on $[\alpha, \beta] \subset [a,b]$ (assuming $\alpha > \beta$), $g'$ on $[\alpha, x_1]$ and so on.

In order to apply MVT, $g$ needs to be continuous on $[a,b]$, $g'$ continuous on $[a,x_1]$, etc. I am not sure how to check this continuity.

I think there should be a way to establish continuity of $g^{(k)}$ on $[a,b]$ for $k = 0, ..., n-1$. Can some one help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption, $f^{(k)}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ for $k=0,\dots,n-1$.  Since $g$ is just $f$ plus some polynomial (namely $-P(t)-M(t-\alpha)^n$), $g^{(k)}$ is just $f^{(k)}$ plus some polynomial, and therefore is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: According to the theorem statement, $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f^{n}(t)$ exists for every $t \in (a,b)$, for a fixed $n$. Is this information enough show that $f^{(k)}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$? If so could you please provide the proof?

Comment: If a function is differentiable then it is continuous.

Comment: Yes but $f^{(n)}$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$. Doesn't this only guarantee that $f^{(k)}$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ (without the end points)? But we need continuity on $[a,b]$.

Comment: But $f^{(n-1)}$ is assumed to be continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: I think I get it. $f^{(n-1)}$ is assumed to be continuous on $[a,b]$. This implies that $f^{(n-2)}$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, which in turn implies that $f^{(n-2)}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Now I can continue inductively to $f^{(0)}$ or $f$.